# How can I get a Look & Feel like Intellij Idea in a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, look-and-feel

As a popular IDE for Java application, Intellij IDEA's look and feel is very beautiful in my opinion.

How did it do that? And how can I get a look and feel like Intellij IDEA in my Swing app?

Comment: IDEA allows for custom Look and Feel.  Is this the default one you like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current IntelliJ IDEA versions come with 3 themes bundled:

- IntelliJ (default light theme)
- Darcula (dark theme)
- High Contrast (accessibility theme)

Darcula theme [is available as a stand alone open source project](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula) and can be reused in your own apps.

---

Original answer from 2011:

By default IDEA uses [Alloy Look&Feel](http://lookandfeel.incors.com/). It's a commercial L&F and it's already quite old and with no updates. One of the major issues with it is that it doesn't support anti-aliasing on most of the platforms.

Therefore, for Windows I'd recommend using Windows L&F. For Mac IDEA already uses Mac specific L&F. Alloy may be worth it only on Linux where most of the other L&Fs look very ugly, though GTK might be a better choice.

Comment: Actually, Alloy isn't a good choice under Linux either.  It looks really ugly without anti-aliasing.  I wonder that it is still the default theme in IDEA.  Fortunately, one can easily change it in the settings.

Comment: This answer is quite old. I doubt if IntelliJ is even using Alloy anymore. Is there an update for the answer to this question?

Answer (score 8):

As far as the **Darcula** theme goes,

> "I'm working on making Darcula a stand alone LaF. The work is almost done and I'm ready to release Darcula v 1.0 alpha or something. This means that you will be able to run you apps like this:
>
> ```
> $ java -cp "darcula.jar:myapplication.jar" -Dswing.laf=Darcula MainClass
> ```
>
> And everything should work
>   I'll do an announce when Darcula is ready for publishing"

Konstantin Bulenkov - June 12, 2013

https://plus.google.com/+jetbrains/posts/NNCSHsjGNXD

I couldn't find any recent follow up info though.

Comment: He seems to have put up a github project here: https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula

Answer (score 5):

Don't know exact look and feel as intellij cause never used it[I'm a Eclipse user]. but following are different options for look and feel:

- [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/index.html)
- [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looksdemo/index.html)
- [Liquid](https://liquidlnf.dev.java.net/)
- [Napkin](http://napkinlaf.sourceforge.net/)
- [Squareness](http://squareness.sourceforge.net/)
- [Geek Farm](http://www.geekfarm.org/emeade/index.html?teknolust_plaf/index.html)
- [InfoNode](http://www.infonode.net/index.html?ilf)
- [Others](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Look-And-Feel-LaF.htm)

Comment: The link for "MLF" points to a project called "Mail Log Filter". Does not seem to be a Java look & feel.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Added it in hurry. Thnx for pointing it out. Removed it.

Answer (score -3):

Many thanks to [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder), [Harry Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559070/harry-joy). 
By default Intellij IDEA uses [Alloy Look&Feel](http://lookandfeel.incors.com/). It's a commercial L&F and it's already quite old and with no updates. One of the major issues with it is that it doesn't support anti-aliasing on most of the platforms. 
In order to maintain consistency in different OS (like Mac OS X, Win, Linux), Alloy Look&Feel may be a good choice. However, I'd use open source L&F like JGoodies.